# Giving viewing access to each group

Tags: joomla-3.x, view, acl, joomla-user-groups

I created three groups (staff, partner & dealer) under same parent - Registered and Viewing to associated groups (staff -> staff, partner -> partner, dealer -> dealer). 
When I wrote a content and giving access to "staff" but Public could see that post also the others group could. 
So I would like to make each groups having each viewing content access. How to give them permission in Joomla 3.x.x?

**Edited** : 
I created a method to hide menu link to each categories which are accessed only specified groups. It looks fine for awhile but I don't like that method.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English.

[image: User Groups]

[image: Viewing Access]

Comment: Set access to "Registered".

Comment: not worked also. I set content to "registered" but it can be seen in Public.

Comment: Are you logged out from back-end? Otherwise you would be logged in in front-end also, therefore you would see content for "Registed".

Comment: I test frontend from another browser. Joomla version is 3.4.1.

Comment: Could you show picture of your usergroups and access levels?

Comment: I edited at my original question, Sir.

Comment: Somebody help me.

Comment: Where are you setting access level (article, menu item etc)? Could you show your link where publically hidden content is shown to public?

Comment: When I have changed three menu items to specified groups, it's kinda okay - only when they logging in, they can see theirs. But if I changed to those three menus to Public and the content view was restricted, Public could see all of them.

Answer (score 1):

User → user groups → viewing access levels → new → select the user group viewing access → give the tittle press save.
Then go to the menu you want to set the viewing access level as you created one.
Make the alteration and press save.